# Order HTML divs to their corresponding div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In this image

[image],

you can see a side menu. There is an offline, online and construction panel. Also there are a few locations, each location is a block(the two buttons are attached to its div). These are hardcoded, I'm trying to automate them instead. based on some values in my code "OFF", "ON" or "construction" the blocks should be ordered to their corresponding panel. What's the best way to do this? I want to see the blocks reposition without having to refresh.

- This is a basic Jsfiddle of the menu above:
       https://jsfiddle.net/3zq4Lpxb/
- Entire HTML for the site menu: https://pastebin.com/e8VKmLZH

FYI: I'm creating a webapplication, using MVC5, ASP.net.

Basic snippet of HTML:

```html
<div id="rightMenu" class="right-area">
  <div class="menu-background"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 right-area-top-buttons">
    <div class="btn btn-dark-themed btn-close-sidemenu" onclick="navigateToPage('CloseRightMenu')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 search-bar">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-dark-themed" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 status-bars">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Offline</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">Isfanbul</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToIsfanbul"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">Monolith</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToMonolith"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Under Construction</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">New Haven</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToNewHaven"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Online</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">JejuIsland</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToJejuIsland"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please paste HTML, CSS and JavaScript only into your snippet instead. We want to see a [mcve]

Comment: What I would do already is turn HTML into something more semantic, like lists, so that you can probably easier manipulate list items. As pointed out in previous comment, getting to see your code would help us to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as specified if the item-group gets one of the 3 classes matching the ID of the panel

```js
const reorderDivs = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".panel")].forEach(panel => {
    const id = panel.id;
    [...document.querySelectorAll("." + id)].forEach(item => {
      const parentContainer = panel.querySelector(".panel-body");
      // console.log(item.querySelector(".item-title").textContent,"moved to",id);
      parentContainer.appendChild(item);
    })
  })
};

// example toggle code

const classes = ['offline', 'construction', 'online'];

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  reorderDivs(); // initialise
  document.getElementById("rightMenu").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // example of a toggle
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("toggle")) {
      const item = tgt.closest(".item-group");
      const classList = item.classList;
      for (let cl of classList) {
        const idx = classes.indexOf(cl);
        if (idx !== -1) { // found
          classList.remove(cl);
          newClass = classes[(idx + 1) % classes.length];
        }
      }
      classList.add(newClass)
      reorderDivs();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="rightMenu" class="right-area">
  <div class="menu-background"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 right-area-top-buttons">
    <div class="btn btn-dark-themed btn-close-sidemenu" onclick="navigateToPage('CloseRightMenu')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 search-bar">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-dark-themed" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 status-bars">
    <div class="panel panel-danger" id="offline">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Offline</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group offline">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">Isfanbul <button class="toggle" type="button">Switch state</button></div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToIsfanbul"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group construction">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">Monolith CONSTRUCTION</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToMonolith"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-warning" id="construction">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Under Construction</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group online">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">New Haven ONLINE</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToNewHaven"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-success" id="online">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Online</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row col-lg-12 item-group offline">
          <div class="col-lg-6 item-title">JejuIsland OFFLINE</div>
          <div class="item-button-group pull-right">
            <button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="item-button" id="JumpToJejuIsland"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more details about how it works? Which values have to changed in order for the position of a location to change to another panel? Can you give an example of a location that changes from the online panel to the offline panel?

Comment: If you change the item-group class from offline to online and run my code, the item will move

Comment: @Falcobezethave a look at the update. The button I added will swap the item between offline, construction and online and wrap